# Does integration by parts work for partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does integration by parts works for partial derivatives? Can we write $$\int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}g(x,y) dx = f(x,y)g(x,y)|_a^b - \int f(x,y)\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}dx$$

Comment: You forgot $dx$ at the end. It works as you have typed, just as long as you look at $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ and $x\mapsto g(x,y)$ as one-variable functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does, for fixed $y$. When you integrate with respect to $x$ we hold $y$ fixed, therefore it is treated as a constant. In other words,

$$\int_a^b x^2 e^{kx} \, dx \quad \text{is equivalent to} \quad \int_a^b x^2 e^{xy} \, dx.$$

There are double/triple integral identities which are known as multivariable integration by parts ([Green identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_identities)).